# Error Building Caffe

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, caffe

I am trying to build caffe with OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, however I keep getting the following error:

libopencv_highgui.so: undefined reference to `avcodec_free_frame@LIBAVCODEC_54'

Any ideas?

Comment: For reference this problem can be solved by explicitly adding the follow flag in the make file: LINK:=  -Wl, rpath, <path to  python lib files>